# CSS Flex layout tabe resize not work in IE

Tags: html, css

I have problem with flex layout. I prepare FIDDLE project where by resizing output box table cells will be one to one beneath. It work´s in chrome, firefox and IE not working with table elemnts tr,td ..

See example: [My problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Klainer/suo8oocm/)

**CSS:**

```
tr {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

td {
    display: block;
}

.cell1 {

}

.cell2{
    width: 500px;
}

.cell3{
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<h1>real table</h1>
<table>
    <tr class="table">
        <td class="cell1">Cell 1</td>
        <td class="cell2">Cell 2</td>
        <td class="cell3">Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h1>div "table"</h1>
<div class="table">
    <span class="cell1">Cell 1</span>
    <span class="cell2">Cell 2</span>
    <span class="cell3">Cell 3</span>
</div>
```

Thanks for help !

Solved:
To work in IE must be set display: block on parents elements tr, table.. Now it works !

Answer (score 0):

IE supports `flex-wrap` on a `tr`, as long as the `tr` has been given an explicit width.

Since you want the width to be based on the window width, you *may* need to use JavaScript:

```
window.onresize= function() {
  var flex= document.querySelectorAll('.table');
  for(var i = 0 ; i < flex.length ; i++) {
    flex[i].style.width= document.body.clientWidth+'px';
  }
}

window.onresize();
```

### Fiddle